# Can't upload video to folder using PHP?

Tags: php, video, xampp, mp4

I'm making a uploading system where the user can upload images and videos, But I'm having problems with the uploading system. Mainly on uploading videos. The images are fine and can be uploaded but the problem starts when I try to upload a video. It's not showing any errors when I try to upload a video So I don't even know what the problem is. This is currently my PHP code:

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['btn-add']))
    {
        $name=$_POST['user_name'];
        $images=$_FILES['profile']['name'];
        $path = "uploads/";
        $rand=rand(1000, 1000000);
        $filename = "$rand.jpg";
        $filepath = "$path$filename";

                function correctImageOrientation($filename) {
  if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
      $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
      if($orientation != 1){
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        $deg = 0;
        switch ($orientation) {
          case 3:
            $deg = 180;
            break;
          case 6:
            $deg = 270;
            break;
          case 8:
            $deg = 90;
            break;
        }
        if ($deg) {
          $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);        
        }
        // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename 
        imagejpeg($img, $filename, 95);
      } // if there is some rotation necessary
    } // if have the exif orientation info
  } // if function exists      
}

        $imgExt=strtolower(pathinfo($images,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"], $filepath); 


        if($imgExt == "jpg" || $imgExt == "jpeg" || $imgExt == "png" || $imgExt == "gif"){

         correctImageOrientation($filepath);


        if ($imgExt == "jpeg" || $imgExt == "jpg") {
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
        }else if($imgExt == "png"){
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
        }else if($imgExt == "gif"){
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);
        }
        $size = getimagesize($filepath);

             $width = imagesx($im);
             $height = imagesy($im);
             $newwidth= 300;
             $newheight= 300;


                if(($width/$newwidth) < ($height/$newheight)){
                    $y = 0;
                    $x = $width - (($height * $newwidth) / $newheight);
                }else{
                    $x = 0;
                    $y = $height - (($width * $newheight) / $newwidth);
                }

             $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor(301, 301);
             imagealphablending($virtual_image, true);
             imagesavealpha($virtual_image, true);



             imagecopyresampled($virtual_image,$im,0,0, $x/2, $y/2, $newwidth, $newheight, $width-$x, $height-$y); 
             $bgcolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($virtual_image,255,255,255,127);

             imagefill($virtual_image,0,0,$bgcolor);

             imagecolortransparent($virtual_image, $bgcolor);


             imagejpeg($virtual_image,$filepath,100);

             }else if ($imgExt == "mp4"){   

             }else echo "Invalid file";



            $stmt=$db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_user(username, picprofile) VALUES (:uname, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic', $filename);
            if($stmt->execute())
        {
            ?>
            <script>

            </script>
            <?php

        }else

        {
            ?>
            <script>

            </script>
        <?php
        }

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment sorry, so i'll just post as an answer but you did not specify what the code should do if the file extension is Mp4

```
   }else if ($imgExt == "mp4"){  
//here should contain your codes and commands if the file is mp4 
 }
```

therefore php does not process the file and also no error, please check the specific upload folder and temp folder